# How do I specify PAYMENTINSTRUCTIONS in BrickLink macros?

Tags: bricklink

There's a line in the default invoice:

```
Payment Instructions: <PAYMENTINSTRUCTIONS>
```

That macro tag is not listed on the [List of E-Mail Basic Macro Tags](https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=661) and on my invoices it seems to always be:

```
Payment Instructions: (not specified)
```

How do I specify a value for `PAYMENTINSTRUCTIONS`?

Comment: I think this question is very specific to Bricklink and we couldn't really help on that. Searching on BL's forum your question there is the only one mentioning tag you are interested in. So it is highly unlikely we have better knowledge than people over Bricklink have.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not belong to any of this site's topics, as outlined in https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic